# Save image output from php script as file

Tags: php, image

I try to have a php script output a generated image as .jpg file:

```
$url = 'http://www.photopost.com/photopost/showfull.php?photo=7541';
file_put_contents('image.jpg',file_get_contents($url));
$page = file_get_contents($url);
echo $page;
```

The echo displays a correct image in the browser.
but image.jpg is not saved.

How can I make this work ?

Comment: you need to set header i think. `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`. follow this http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php url

Comment: ini setting check   echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');

Comment: $url = "http://www.domain.com/showphoto.php?photo=10" in url can not find image

Comment: $url = 'http://www.photopost.com/photopost/showfull.php?photo=7541';

Comment: ini_get('allow_url_fopen'); shows: 1

Answer (score 1):

You need to output a Content-Type header with a proper MIME type for the browser to be able to understand what kind of file the server is sending.

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php and https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/ for a list of valid MIME types.

Comment: I tried: code <?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$url = 'http://www.photopost.com/photopost/showfull.php?photo=7541';
file_put_contents('image.jpg',file_get_contents($url));
?>

Comment: Have you specified a path for the image to be saved in? (I.e. `file_put_contents('/tmp/image.jpg', $data);`)
The default path will probably not be writeable by the web server. Can the web server/PHP process write to that path? You need to provide the error for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

**Getting image from url using curl :-**

```
$profile_Image = 'http://www.photopost.com/photopost/showfull.php?photo=7541'; //image url
$userImage = 'myimg.jpg'; // renaming image
$path = '';  // your saving path
$ch = curl_init($profile_Image);
$fp = fopen($path . $userImage, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

**Getting image from url using file_get_contents :-**

```
$profile_Image = 'http://www.photopost.com/photopost/showfull.php?photo=7541'; //image url
$userImage = 'myimg.jpg'; // renaming image
$path = '';  // your saving path
$thumb_image = file_get_contents($profile_Image);
if ($http_response_header != NULL) {
    $thumb_file = $path . $userImage;
    file_put_contents($thumb_file, $thumb_image);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jinandra, thansk for your help. This code downloads a file, bot not recognized on my pc as a valid jpg!

Answer (score 0):

Change your url from

```
http://www.photopost.com/photopost/showfull.php?photo=7541 //html document
```

to

```
http://www.photopost.com/photopost/watermark.php?file=7541 //downloadable url
```

Then use code from other answers or use `imagecreatefromjpeg`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Comment: Dave thanks, this works! (my vote not yet visible due to low reputation)